# Sentence structure concerning phrases/subjects

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, commas

Can 'Shildon Football clubs top striker' be viewed both as an introductory phrase or the main subject of the sentence depending on comma placement?

1. Shildon Football club's top striker, Daniel Moore has played well this season.

(Daniel Moore has played well this season.)

2. Shildon Football club's top striker has played well this season.

Shildon Football club's top striker, Daniel Moore, has played well this season.

Answer (score 2):

The two noun phrases "Shildon Football club's top striker" and "Daniel Moore" are in apposition.  Literally they are two nouns placed next to each other. Each can act as a modifier of the other.  Together they form the subject of the sentence

The commas mark this as a non-restrictive appositive.  You would normally put commas on both sides of the name "Daniel Moore" in this non-restrictive sense.  It is called "non-restrictive" because the initial phrase has already identified a single person, and adding the name gives additional information about this person.  Compare with  "Shildon striker Daniel Moore has played well"  Here there may be several strikers, the name identifies which one.